# Element click event not actually working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I don't seem to get it. All I'm attempting to do for now is log the text inside of a specific element - #target - on a webpage when it is clicked. Is there anything obvious that might cause the following not to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#target").click(function(){
    var selectorText = jQuery("#target").text();
    console.log(selectorText);
});

</script>
```

- I originally had it loading inside of document ready but dropped it
  as I don't actually attempt to click the #target until the page is
  fully loaded.
- jQuery is successfully loaded.
- No errors in console.
- The #target is properly loaded inside
  of the DOM before the script is reached (near the end of the of
  document).

Comment: Can you recreate this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Do you receive any error in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQuery("#target")` Your `#target`does not exist before the DOM is loaded therefore jQuery can't attach a listener to it. Whether you do attempt to click it or not does not matter.

If you really don't want to put it in `$()`, try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#target", function(){
    //do your thing
});
```

Comment: Document ready would have solved that but I have it loaded in the footer after #target is created.

Comment: @deeperDATA - What do you mean by "footer"?

Comment: This script is placed after the creation of #target. I have it loaded in the very bottom section of the <body>.

Comment: @deeperDATA - Make sure jQuery is loaded and the `id` is correct.

Comment: Any reason why this would work flawlessly in Firefox but not Chrome? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: @deeperDATA - Actually this should work in all browsers. If it doesn't work in Chrome then there must be error somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your element has been dynamically created, try to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#target', (function(){
    var selectorText = $(this).text();
    console.log(selectorText);
});
```

Also, make sure that you only add `#target` once since `id` is unique. If you intend to create it multiple times, then you need to use class instead.

Btw, for delegated event, you should bind them to the closest parent that is not dynamic instead of `document`.

Comment: Any reason why this would work flawlessly in Firefox but not Chrome?